# Proof linearly independent unit vectors of subspace $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

How to proof this theorem?

Let $S$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$ of dimension $k\geq 2$, and let $\mathbf{w}\neq \mathbf{0}$ be a vector in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Then there are at least $k-1$ linearly independent unit vectors in $S$ that are orthogonal to $\mathbf{w}$.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Selamat Datang di MSE. Try to show what you already did and where you get stuck. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for more.